# Serializing nested object to string in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, json, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am trying to connect my Django application to the mailchimps API with help from the Django Rest Framework, if I want to create a batch operation, I need to send the following call:

```
{
  "operations": [
    {
      "method": "PUT",
      "path": "lists/abc123/members/817f1571000f0b843c2b8a6982813db2",
      "body": "{\"email_address\":\"hall@hallandoates.com\", \"status_if_new\":\"subscribed\"}"
    },...
  ]
}
```

As you can see, the body object should be a json string. To create these calls, I created a model operation:

**models.py**

```
class Operation(object):
    def __init__(self, method, list, contact):
        email_clean = contact.email_address.lower().encode('utf-8')
        subscriber_hash = hashlib.md5(email_clean).hexdigest()
        serializer = ContactSerializer(contact)
        body = serializer.data

        self.method = method
        self.path = "lists/%s/members/%s" % (list, subscriber_hash)
        self.body = body
```

And the following serializer:

**serializer.py**

```
class OperationSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    method = serializers.CharField()
    path = serializers.CharField()
    body = serializers.CharField(allow_blank=True, required=False)
```

When I use my serializer to generate JSON, and parse the data with JSONRenderer(), the following call is returned:

```
{
  "operations": [
    {
      "method": "PUT",
      "path": "lists/abc123/members/817f1571000f0b843c2b8a6982813db2",
      "body": "{\'email_address\':\'hall@hallandoates.com\', \'status_if_new\':\'subscribed\'}"
    },...
  ]
}
```

This call breaks because of the single quotes, can anyone help me a hand in solving this?

Comment: Quick check - what if you would replace `self.body = body` with `self.body = json.dumps(body)` - any difference? Thanks.

Comment: That adds the double quotes, but also to backslashes. So \\"email_address\\" etc. That also breaks...

Comment: You need to sanitize your data before they got saved to the DB.

Comment: What do you exactly mean Linovia? Isn't this data sanitized?